# C# - Can I define a property's "set" method with extra actions without creating a private var for the value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Usually, I see things implemented like this:

```cs
private string _privateProperty;
public string PublicProperty 
{
    get { return _privateProperty; }
    set { DoSomething(); _privateProperty = value; }
}
```

But is it really necessary to have this extra var?
Can't I do something similar to `{ get; set; }` containing the extra method?

```
//pseudo code
public string PublicProperty { get; set {DoSomething(); <set_value>; }
```

Comment: `But is it really necessary to have this extra var`, as of now yes it is.

Comment: You can also look into https://github.com/Fody/Fody and https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged   but it may bring more troubles than what it solves depending on your use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties):

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make
>   property-declaration more concise **when no additional logic is required**
>   in the property accessors.

So for the time being you can’t.